# Ola scripts = log shipping and transaction logs

Tags: ola-hallengren

We use the Ola Hallengren scripts for full/diff/tran log backups.  Ola's site indicates that log shipping is compatible unless we are using transaction logs.  Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your answer lies in another answer here on StackExchange.  [Transaction log shipping together with backup job = conflict?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6916158).

> The log shipping process does its work by taking log backups. There
> cannot be another job that does the same, it will break the log backup
> chain. See [Using Log Shipping as Part of a Recovery Plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms175480(v=sql.105)). Your
> recovery strategy should clearly document the location of the log
> backups as taken by the log shipping job and detail step-by-step
> instructions how to recover the database using these log backups. You
> should also test this strategy to validate it.
>
> If you create a maintenance plan (or Ola backup) for a database that is configured as
> a log shipping database, do not have the maintenance plan create
> transaction log backups. If a maintenance plan and log shipping both
> attempt to create transaction log backups of the same database, log
> shipping will not function correctly. You can do full and differential
> database backups through your maintenance plan (or Ola backup) without any conflict
> with log shipping.

According to Ola's [Frequently Asked Questions](https://ola.hallengren.com/frequently-asked-questions.html)

**Does the SQL Server Maintenance Solution support log shipping?**

> The SQL Server Maintenance Solution supports log shipping. Full and
> differential backup, integrity check, and index and statistics
> maintenance are performed on the primary database. Transaction log
> backups are not performed on databases that are involved in log
> shipping.

---

So, if you implement Log Shipping, just keep in mind that **THAT** process will be taking your transaction log backups and **NOT** Ola's process.